# Not Time Slider for KML w/ Timestamps

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm working with a large team to try and plot a series of events over time using Google Earth.  We're trying to add timestamps to each event to enable us to filter the events we're viewing by time, but we can't get the time slider on Google Earth to open up and allow us to filter.

Right now, we're simply going in for every placemark and adding the timestamp under Placemark>Properties>View>Time/Date.  We've successfully opened other KMLs with timestamped data and had the time slider show up, so we're not sure what we're doing wrong.

I've gone through the tutorial/instructions provided at https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time#gps
https://support.google.com/earth/answer/183758?hl=en
as well as did searches of the Google Earth help forums, but was unable to find any information that addressed our particular issue.

We're currently running Google Earth 7.1.1.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

If you add time to a placemark in Google Earth using Placemark > Properties > View > Time/Date then you're actually setting the time by which [historical imagery](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148094?hl=en) as the base map is viewed when the placemark is activated. This function in Google Earth adds a `<gx:TimeStamp>` or `<gx:TimeSpan>` to the placemark's view (LookAt or Camera) which doesn't define the time at which the placemark is visible. In other words, it sets the range of time slider not the placemark. The time slider controls historical imagery, sunlight, and visibility of time-stamped features.

The Google Earth and Google Earth Pro clients do not allow you to add times to your placemarks from which they become visible when the timer slider changes. This and other limitations of Google Earth with respect to editing KML is discussed in the [KML Errata](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#limits).

To add `<TimeStamp>` or `<TimeSpan>` elements to your KML you must edit the raw KML outside of Google Earth.

```
 <Placemark>
      <TimeStamp>
        <when>2007-01-14T21:05:02Z</when>
      </TimeStamp>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-122.536226,37.86047</coordinates>
      </Point>
 </Placemark>
```